# Why does Oracle sysdate seem to return older dates after it has returned newer dates?

Tags: oracle, plsql

In the app I work on we track the time passed between two button clicks. When the button is clicked the first time a new row is inserted into a table, and `start_date` set from `sysdate`:

`insert into MY_TABLE (..., start_date) values (..., sysdate);`

Then, when the button is clicked the second time, the `end_date` for the same row is set:

`update MY_TABLE set end_date = sysdate where id = input_id;`

The problem is that sometimes - not all the time, but maybe 1/5 of the time - `start_date` is some 20 seconds higher than `end_date`.

Any ideas about how this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I found out that it is due to us using an Oracle cluster, and `sysdate` getting date time from multiple different servers.

Comment: Are they not synchronized by NTP or GPS?